# How to implement a ListView's like without Scrollbar in a CarouselPage with Xamarin?

Tags: listview, xamarin, scrollbar, cross-platform, carousel

In my Xamarin's project, I'm using a CarouselView. I have a Scrollview in the carousel's datatemplate, and in this Scrollview, I have some elements(Grid, Labels, etc) and a ListView. Problem : there are 2 scrollbars in my content. I want to disable the scrollbar of the Listview so I can show every elements of my Listview in my carousel's datatemplate but it's not possible with the Listview of Xamarin.

I can't access to my Xaml's elements because of the CarouselPage's datatemplate. So I can't do it programatically with C#. (or I missed something, it's not impossible!)

I just want to show all my elements (mySource) with my custom ViewCell in the datatemplate of the Carousel without a second scrollbar.

I have something like this :

```html
<CarouselView>
  <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
          <!-- Some items in the Grid then the ListView-->
          <ListView ItemSource = "{Binding mySource}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <!-- my custom view -->
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </Grid>
      </ScrollView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

PS : sorry for my english

Comment: A ScrollView can have a header so you can embbed your grids and co in it (not relevant but good to know I think). I can't currently think of a view element which would not be scrollable and provide you the possibility to use a datatemplate out of the box... Maybe you can use a classic template and programmatically add them in a stacklayout in your code behind. like `<StackLayout x:Name="Stack" />` in your xaml and `foreach(var element in Elements){ var view = new MyView(){ Name = element.Name, ...}; Stack.Children.Add(view); }` in your code behind. That's the best I can think of. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said before, I have to use a CarouselView there, so if I add a StackLayout I won't be able to access it in my code behind. But thanks for the tips about the header, didn't know that

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the itemtemplate in the CarouselView... I'm not used to that component atm